# Does label need an input to go with (web standards)?

Tags: html, label, accessibility

This is a bit of a technicality, best practices / standards question. Everything I read about the `<label>` tag talks about using it along with an `<input>` tag (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label). There are also reources discussing the pros/cons of having an `input` field without a `label`.

However, I have not explicitly seen anything that says whether `label` can or cannot be used standalone, without being paired with an `input` tag.

Can anyone point me to any documentation/standards/resources that suggest a best practice on whether to use a `label` without an `input` or would a `span` suffice for that purpose?

Comment: I mean you can, but the question is why? Do you have a use case in mind because almost certainly the answer is, "yes, use a `<span>` instead, a `<label>` without an input, while valid, does not make any semantic sense!"

Answer (score 1):

A `<label>` can only be applied to [certain labelable elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#labelable-element), either through the `for` attribute, or by wrapping the element in the `<label>` tag.

So, it doesn't have to only be an `<input>` specifically, but it can't be a `span` either. A `label` can be applied to any interactive form control element that is defined in the spec, but it can't be applied to static content, as that would be invalid HTML.

It's not technically invalid to have an unassociated `label` on a page, but I can't imagine that it would be a good experience for anyone using assistive technology, or why anyone would want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

A label does not need an associated labeled control.

[The specs of the `label` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-label-element) authorize it specifically:

> Except where otherwise specified by the following rules, a `label` element has no labeled control.

*The two following rules contain the known usage : using the `for` attribute, or when the `label` contains a labelable element*